# Visual Studio 2017 Django project problem

Tags: django, visual-studio

I'm new to Visual Studio 2017. I created a new Django project and download Django 2.0 But the syntax of files created by vs is based on Django 1.x version. How to get latest Django syntax files.

### Edit

I create new project in Visual Studio and select Django project then it creates some files that are required for project then after it I install Django latest version which is 2.x but the syntax of project files (like: urls.py  which syntax is differ in Django version 1.x and 2,x) is written according to Django 1.x.

[image]

In this image one left side Django project v 1.x open and on right side 2.x open.

Comment: I did not get your question, (sorry for that). Do check your django version. If you are using 2.0 I guess python 3.5 will be perfect. If you are having problem with `pylint` on vs, then it is not working perfectly with python 3.6 or above, better to use 3.5.

Comment: I create new project in visual studio and select django project then it creates some files that are required for project then after it i install djnago latest version which is 2.x but the syntax of project files(like: urls.py which synatx is differ in django version 1.x and 2,x) is written according to django 1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a list of things first:

1. Change MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE.
2. Get rid of `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',` from MIDDLEWARE
3. Next add this function to views.py 
   `def login(request):
   assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
   return render(
       request,
       'app/login.html',
       {
           'title':'Login',
       }
   )`
4. Then update urls.py import module list to include
   `from app import views`
5. Last, [New URL snippet to add in urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCFUL.png)

Your login page for django 2.1.4 should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok when transforming a Django 1.x to 2.x project in vs you need to do some things:
`django.contrib.auth.views.login` doesnt exist in 2.x anymore you need to use 
`django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView.as_view()` just write this instead of login in your urls.py and change directory of your logintemplate into a new directory: registration do the same with logout and stuff.
The 2nd thing is you need to rename the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings.py to MIDDLEWARE cause that also changed in django 2.x. 
After these changes it should work